# Python POST request doesn't send request until after waiting for duration of timeout period on google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-requests, timeout

I am making a python POST request using the `python-requests` library

```
import requests

# Set token, headers, data variables here

r = requests.post(f'https://api.popularwebsite.com/endpoint?access_token={token}', headers=headers, data=data)

timetaken = r.elapsed.total_seconds()
```

This code is taking a long time to run, and at the end, the `timetaken` variable is some value between 127 and 128, however the request is successful. I can add some logging and in the logs, I can see the request isn't sent until after 127 seconds

Logging code:

```
import logging

import http.client
http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True
```

Logs:

```
2021-03-15 (04:02:01.522) DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.popularwebsite.com:443
2021-03-15 (04:04:08.646) send: b'{"myJsonPayload": 1234}'
```

Additionally, I can pass a timeout argument of n seconds to the post function. This changes how long the request waits, but the program will still sit idle for n seconds before making the request. At the end, `timetaken` > n and `timetaken` < n+1.

This is in the context of a python flask application deployed on Google App Engine. Oddly, it seems the conditions that cause this issue are the combination of my server and this api. I can make requests to other endpoints without issue from my server. I can also run the python code locally and make requests to the problematic api from my PC without issue. Some local environment issue on the server must be messing up requests for this particular url. This app has been making requests to this endpoint without issue for 2 years, and spontaneously started experiencing this issue a few days ago

I have tried redeploying my app onto my server, and this might fix the issue for the first request or two, but then the issue will return. I have also attempted deploying a previous version of the code, to no avail. This confirms the issue is not due to a code change.

Any ideas what could be causing this, or how I should go about troubleshooting?

Edit: The issue seems sporadic. It will start up and go away unpredictably

Edit: Here is my app.yaml file

```
runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT --chdir src main:app --timeout 300
instance_class: F1

env_variables:
    KEY1: "value1"
```

[image: Sequence diagrams]

Comment: Do you check Stackdriver Logging for your App Engine service? Please check if you are getting any errors or warning when making your Post Request

Comment: Could you please show the output of the request to your endpoint using [curl](https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/08c5d85437d5d4f00e58#examples) ?

Comment: Please share your app.yaml file. And please share the version of Python you are using.

Comment: @NibrassH There are no errors or warnings when making the request. The curl request works as expected from my local environment (as does a request using python requests on my local machine). I am using python 3.7.5 and requests 2.25.1. I updated the post with my app.yaml file

Comment: did you try a packet sniffer such as ethereal? to see if the packets are not sent, or if the ssl tunel buildup takes long, etc. maybe dns resolving times out at a server and fails over after timeout to another one. If no packet to the server is sent before the timeout, i would suspect the dns

Comment: @Mirronelli Is it possible to run a packet sniffer on app engine? If so, can you provide some more direction on how to do this?

Comment: Sorry maybe I missunderstood the scenario. You mentioned you server, your PC, and some API. I did not get where the code that sends the request resides. Which one is on the google app engine, etc. If you could clarify please. Also I have noticed in the log that there is a connection pool that logs the start of the request. Could it be that the request waits for the pool to provide a connection? In other words might the pool be exhausted, because some other previously ran connection is timing out? I would maybe investigate into the pool. Log its state before attempting the request etc.

Comment: Could you please try to deploy again with --no-cache [flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#--no-cache) as following: gcloud app deploy --no-cache?

Comment: If deploying with "--no-cache" works, it's likely due to a cached library dependency.
On the other hand, could you please remove the environment variable from your app.yaml file and try to deploy again?

Comment: @NibrassH deploying using --no-cache and removing the environment variable did not solve the issue

Comment: @Mirronelli Updated the post with sequence diagrams to clarify

Comment: thanks. i would continue by troubleshooting the pool. is there a way how to ask urllib to produce more detailed logs?  I have seen people having similar problems [here](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1535). For them it was a bug in urllib when working with mutliprocessing/threading. Do you use mutlithreading or processing explicitly by your code?

Comment: @Mirronelli I am not explicitly using multiprocessing, but it's possible gunicorn or app engine are starting up multiple instances of my server. I'll try diving into urllib more

Comment: also in the log I can see that the uri it is trying to access is "api.popularwebsite.com.com" is that com.com intentional?

Comment: @Mirronelli ah, just a mistake when editing the logs as an example for this post. The real logs don't have that. Fixed the post

Comment: @quantumbutterfly can you try to hit that api which your app on google-app engine is hitting via some tool like ab testing tool and post the results on the question please?

Comment: from what i can understand, the service which is responsible for handling your request might be overloaded and because of that your requests might be held in the request queue, until the service is free to handle your request

Comment: @kumarD as I mention in the post, hitting the popularwebsite.com api from any source other than app engine works as expected. Popularwebsite is a stand-in for Facebook's messaging api. I'm only sending ~100 requests per day and a maximum of about 5 per minute, so I highly doubt Facebook's servers are overloaded with this level of use

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a caching issue performed by the client, Please try to clear your browser cache as I suppose that the browser was the one doing the cache-ing.

Please note re-deploying a new version of the app will not remove the cache.  So you can use the **[`default_expiration`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#default_expiration)** element of **Google App Engine** to configure the time a static resource will be cached in web proxies and browsers.

In most cases, the default 10-minute expiration time is appropriate.”

If you would like caching to be refreshed quicker, then you can override it to a lower time (down to 0) by adding the following .yaml [element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#default_expiration):

```
default_expiration: 0s.
```

That will override the global expiration time, or if you wish to only set it for certain handlers, you can use the [following](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#handlers_expiration).

Comment: There are no browsers or static resources involved. I have updated the post with sequence diagrams to clarify. When the issue is occurring, it affects all clients simultaneously

Comment: In this case, I would like you to contact [Google Cloud Platform Support](https://cloud.google.com/support) in order to see what could be the issue since it needs inspection of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder which app engine are you using. The  app engine **flexible** or **standard**

If it's **standard**  and if there is no load then it Scales to zero and after your next call, it took time.  But if it's **flexible** then a minimum of 1 instance would be there. If that is not the case you have to check other reasons.

If that is the case: One workaround you can set min instance for *app engine standard*

[image: Comparing high-level features]

Comment: The issue has definitely been narrowed down to something occurring in the python request library. The app is definitely not scaled to zero

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to troubleshoot, and created a new GCP project in a different region and migrated. No more issues